# Not able to define logic in else for pattern printing

Tags: python, design-patterns

Got stuck expected pattern printing

Below is my code , I have printed the first part but got stuck with else part printing
required some input how to build logic for else part

```
n=29
breaking= int((n+1)/2)
lst  = [ len(str(num).zfill(2)) * ' ' for num in reversed(range(1,n+1)) ]
cnt=-1
for row in range(1,n+1):

  if row <= breaking:
    lst[cnt]=str(row).zfill(2) + '   '
    print(' '.join(lst))
    cnt = cnt - 1 
    
  else:
```

**Expected output :**

```
                                          01   
                                       02    01   
                                    03    02    01   
                                 04    03    02    01   
                              05    04    03    02    01   
                           06    05    04    03    02    01   
                        07    06    05    04    03    02    01   
                     08    07    06    05    04    03    02    01   
                  09    08    07    06    05    04    03    02    01   
               10    09    08    07    06    05    04    03    02    01   
            11    10    09    08    07    06    05    04    03    02    01   
         12    11    10    09    08    07    06    05    04    03    02    01   
      13    12    11    10    09    08    07    06    05    04    03    02    01   
   14    13    12    11    10    09    08    07    06    05    04    03    02    01   
15    14    13    12    11    10    09    08    07    06    05    04    03    02    01
   14    13    12    11    10    09    08    07    06    05    04    03    02    01
      13    12    11    10    09    08    07    06    05    04    03    02    01
         12    11    10    09    08    07    06    05    04    03    02    01
            11    10    09    08    07    06    05    04    03    02    01
               10    09    08    07    06    05    04    03    02    01
                  09    08    07    06    05    04    03    02    01
                     08    07    06    05    04    03    02    01
                        07    06    05    04    03    02    01
                           06    05    04    03    02    01
                              05    04    03    02    01
                                 04    03    02    01
                                    03    02    01
                                       02    01
                                          01
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Here's what you can do:

#### Code

```
n = int(input('Enter max value : '))
num_width = len(str(n))
seperation = '    '
tot_width = num_width * n + len(seperation) * (n-1)

for i in list(range(1, n + 1)) + list(range(n - 1, 0, -1)):
    line = seperation.join([str.rjust(str(j), num_width, '0') for j in range(i, 0, -1)])
    print(str.center(line, tot_width))
```

#### Output

[image: output pattern]

#### Explanation

> First `for loop` iterates over `max-value allowed in the current line` to be printed.

> Second `for loop` iterates over each number to be printed (i.e. from `1` to `max-value in the current line` in reverse order.

#### Code Explained line by line

```
n = int(input('Enter max value : '))        # Get the max value for the pattern

# Know the length of highest value in the pattern so that we can make all the digits
# in the pattern of that width by adding zeroes
# for eg. if max number is 15, width is 2, max number is 178, width is 3..
num_width = len(str(n))

# The seperation to be added between 2 digits
seperation = '    '

# calculating max width of the pattern (which occurs at the middlemost line)
tot_width = n  *  num_width                   +      len(seperation) * (n-1)
#           (n digits of 'num-width' length)  +    (n-1) number of seperations between them

# i will go initially from 1 to n, which is : list(range(1, n + 1))
# then will decrease from n to 1,  which is : list(range(n - 1, 0, -1))
for i in list(range(1, n + 1)) + list(range(n - 1, 0, -1)):
    digits = []
    for j in range(i, 0, -1):  # now j will iterate from current value of 'i' to '1' in decreasing order

        # each digit in current line is created with a width of 'num-width' by adding preceding zeroes
        digits.append(str.rjust(str(j), num_width, '0'))

    # Finally, join all the digits with 'seperation' in between to create the line
    line = seperation.join(digits)
    print(str.center(line, tot_width))         # now center the line by adding spaces on both the sides, and print it
```

###### This code universally works for any value of `n`

Comment: :  May i know why their is a need for 2 for loop. Can you brief your code step by step

Comment: Sure, I've added explanation for you in the answer :)

Comment: Can you write the code in easy way. you have written in one linear .. not getting your approach. but it work like charm for me

Comment: Okay, so I've added highly commented code to the answer, check it.                       I've expanded some lines like list comprehensions into separate code lines for better understanding.                                                                                                         Once you understand, you can refer the earlier code, as it's short, and also uses Python's strong concepts like [list-comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists).

Comment: :  can you provide your input to this question as well : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70532910/issue-with-else-part-printing-pattern

Comment: There's only single input, and that's in the first line: `n = int(input('Enter max value : '))` where you will provide maximum value of `n` (in your question, it's `15`)

Answer (score 0):

It's messy, but it works. Let me know in the comments and I will explain.

```
for i in range(1, n//2 + 1):
    print(" "*(n+1-2*i) + "  ".join(["{:02d}".format(i - j) for j in range(i)]))
for i in range(n//2 + 1, 0, -1):
    print(" "*(n+1-2*i) + "  ".join(["{:02d}".format(i - j) for j in range(i)]))
```

Comment: : Not working the code is printing the pattern different

Comment: You might need to edit the indices, but that should work.