# issue with else part printing pattern

Tags: python

I am trying to print below pattern. But not able to able to achieve down word pattern
Any suggestion or concise approach

**Expected output :**

```
                   01 
                02 01 
             03 02 01 
          04 03 02 01 
       05 04 03 02 01 
          04 03 02 01
             03 02 01
                02 01
                   01
```

**code :**

```
n=10
var=''
breaking = int((n+1)/2)
dec = 2
space=2
cnt=1
for row in range(1,n+1):
  if row <= breaking:
    print(' ' * ( (n - 1) * 3 ) + str(row).zfill(2) + ' ' + var )
    var = str(row).zfill(2) + ' ' + var 
    n = n-1
  else:
    print(' ' *  ((n*2) + (breaking + space) + cnt) + var[dec:])
    space = space + 2
    dec = dec + 2
    cnt = cnt + 1
```

**The above code printed abnormal pattern in down side how to fix it ?**

```
                   01 
                02 01 
             03 02 01 
          04 03 02 01 
       05 04 03 02 01 
           04 03 02 01 
             4 03 02 01 
                03 02 01 
                    02 01 
                      2 01
```

Comment: Number of spaces must decrease in lower half. E. g. you can (instead of the "if") create two for-loops, one for upper half, then a second for lower half where row number decreases ("step" parameter of "range"). This makes things much easier.

Comment: `print(' ' *  ((n*2) + (breaking + space) + cnt) + var[dec:])` In your own words, what is the purpose of this part of the code? Did you try to check the value that it calculates for `((n*2) + (breaking + space) + cnt) + var[dec:])`? Can you figure out by hand what the values should be? Do you get the correct result?

Comment: Please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and try to trace through the logic of your code a step at a time.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is you are increasing `cnt` with every iteration of the loop in the else block, when in reality, you don't need it when you are below the 1/2 way point. Try this instead: (I renamed some of your variables for readability.

```py
rows = 10
var = ''
peak = int((rows + 1) / 2)
dec = 2
space = 2
count = 1
for row in range(1, rows + 1):
    if row <= peak:
        print(' ' * ((rows - 1) * 3) + str(row).zfill(2) + ' ' + var)
        var = str(row).zfill(2) + ' ' + var
        rows = rows-1
    else:
        print(' ' * ((rows * 2) + (peak + space)) + var[dec:])
        # print(' ' * ((rows * 2) + (peak + space) + count) + var[dec:])
        space = space + 2
        dec = dec + 2
        # cnt = cnt + 1
```

Comment: code as some issue not able to delete single digit

Answer (score 1):

a very different approach with some f-strings:

```
def f(n):
    width = 3 * n - 1
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        print(f'{" ".join(f"{j:02d}" for j in range(i, 0, -1)):>{width}s}')
    for i in range(n - 1, 0, -1):
        print(f'{" ".join(f"{j:02d}" for j in range(i, 0, -1)):>{width}s}')
```

`f(n=5)` then outputs:

```
            01
         02 01
      03 02 01
   04 03 02 01
05 04 03 02 01
   04 03 02 01
      03 02 01
         02 01
            01
```

`f"{j:02d}"` prints the integer `j` using 2 characters and zero-padding. `f'{...:>{width}s}'` is a string with `width` characters, right-aligned with no padding. the numbers are generated with the `range` objects.

if `i=3` in the first loop, the `range` object in the print statement will be `range(3, 0, -1)` i.e. generating the numbers `3, 2, 1`. [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)ing those with `" ".join(...)` and zero-padding will result in the string `"03 02 01"`. this string is then right-aligned in the `width` characters reserved by `f'{...:>{width}s}'`.

---

slightly more elegant:

```
from itertools import chain

def f(n):
    width = 3 * n - 1
    for i in chain(range(1, n + 1), range(n - 1, 0, -1)):
        print(f'{" ".join(f"{j:02d}" for j in range(i, 0, -1)):>{width}s}')
```

---

**UPDATE**

if you want this to work for numbers with more than 2 digits, you also have to parametrize the width of the integers `i_width`:

```
from itertools import chain

def f(n):
    i_width = len(str(n))
    width = (i_width + 1) * n - 1
    for i in chain(range(1, n + 1), range(n - 1, 0, -1)):
        print(f'{" ".join(f"{j:0{i_width}d}" for j in range(i, 0, -1)):>{width}s}')
```

Comment: : can you explain in brief step by step this method seems unique but not getting what you are doing

Comment: not printing expected output

Comment: can you run in google colab .. i took input n = 13 it as not given me proper output. it is coming ka reverse some boat [ navy ship ]

Comment: ok, the display `width` is now calculated from `n`. https://colab.research.google.com/drive/12ImyjDu6321eF0vnRDvUsCMzLhHEvJVC

Comment: @hiro protagonist : The code might not for 3 digit input. Try input n = 220

Comment: @codeholic24 the last version of the code takes that into account.

Answer (score 1):

It looks very difficult to fixed the provided code.
So, just give my code here,

```py
>>> def f(n):
...     print('\n'.join(map(' '.join, [[f'{n-i:0>2d}' if i+1 > abs(n-j-1) else '  ' for i in range(n)] for j in range(2*n-1)])))
...
>>> f(5)
            01
         02 01
      03 02 01
   04 03 02 01
05 04 03 02 01
   04 03 02 01
      03 02 01
         02 01
            01
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of giving or calculating result for `row>breaking`, you can stor the result till `row<breaking` in a stack and then for `row>breaking` pop the stack and print result

```
n=13
var=''
breaking = int((n+1)/2)
dec = 2
space=2
cnt=1
stack =[]
for row in range(1,n+1):
  if row <=breaking:
    x = ' ' * ( (n - 1) * 3 ) + str(row).zfill(2) + ' ' + var 
    print(x)
    if row!=breaking:
        stack.append(x)
    var = str(row).zfill(2) + ' ' + var 
    n = n-1
  else:
    if stack:
        print(stack.pop())
```

Comment: your code will not work for 3 digit value as you have set `zfill` to 2. Make it as generic. The padding of zeros should happen by default in order to match the length of n. try input n = 220

Comment: @codeholic24 i took op code and modified it to his requirements